# How can I force chrome to use proxy like as ProxyCap by C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, proxy

I am developing my personal software by C#.
I want to use proxy in Google chrome. At present I am doing by the following code. [How to use proxy with C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512645/how-to-use-proxy-with-c-sharp-application)

ProxyCap can force a program to use proxy without setting proxy(in internet options).

Now I want something like Proxy Cap in my C# apps. I will choose IP and will force a program to use that.