# C# WebBrowser Control Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, webbrowser-control

How to implement Proxy in C# WebBrowser control/Component.

What I want to know, is how to implement proxy, so my C# webBrowser control use this proxy for browsing when its run.

I also don't want to change proxy through registry ... because it affect my normal Browsing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a proxy for Webbrowser Control without effecting the SYSTEM/IE proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499568/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-webbrowser-control-without-effecting-the-system-ie-proxy)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
private Uri currentUri;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentUri = new Uri(@"http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
            //WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("208.52.92.160:80");
            //myRequest.Proxy = myProxy;

            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

            webBrowser1.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();

            webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigating);
        }

        void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != "blank")
            {
                currentUri = new Uri(currentUri, e.Url.AbsolutePath);
                HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(currentUri);

                HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

                webBrowser1.DocumentStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

You'll have to play with it a little, but I was able to browse around the site.

Or you can try modifying the WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy setting:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx

Comment: Then what?  Intercept all navigation events to use your own `HttpWebRequest` again?

Comment: I don't think you can set WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy, but you can intercept it yourself and create your own navigation.

Comment: Good technique (I upvoted) - however this does not cover postbacks and cookies

Comment: @NickBray will this solution work if the web page being requested has a lot of images, scripts, etc, which need to pass through the proxy server? How does one attempt to do an end-2-end test of this solution?

Comment: This worked great for me to load the initial page, but when using `Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")` it won't load the next page. The `currentUri` variable is set to blank and the screen just displays a white page. Is there a way to capture the stream from clicking the button?

Comment: the problem is, document is loaded using the proxy stream but,,, rest of its contents like js files and images or even a frame url is loaded using non proxy connection. i am also looking for a work around, but it seems the control itself is made not to have individual settings or proxy but to use what ever the real ie supplies....