# Does changing webBrowser settings affect Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, winforms

Say I change the user agent, or the proxy of the webBrowser, will this effect Internet Explorer aswell?

Just wondering, thanks!

Comment: You can change it to watever you want. By user-agent I mean the http header ofc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no. It will only affect Internet Explorer if you make changes directly to the Registry. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: Changing the proxy requires changing the registry. So it will effect IE?

Comment: Yes. All type of changes made to the registry will reflect on IE once any open IE instances are closed and reopened.

Comment: Is there an other way to change the proxy besides tweaking the registry then?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you might have to work directly with the HttpRequest/Response. See: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035911/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-proxy`

Comment: I already know how to do that, I need a way to do it with WebBrowser.