# Using a proxy through WebRequest not reading the proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, webbrowser-control

I tried using the debugger and it runs through just as it should
I am trying to use a proxy to connect through IExplorer.
and yeah well.. its not using the proxy I am providing it and its not giving me any errors aswell.. Did I miss something?

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        var myproxy = new WebProxy(proxyBox.Text, false);
        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Very unclear what you want to set proxy for browser and webrequest are two different things a d changing proxy for one doesn't impact another

Comment: How should I explain it? new to using proxies

Comment: You are creating a `WebRequest` and calling `GetResponse`.  This has nothing to do with your web browser control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WebBrowser Control Proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035911/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-proxy)