# how to set proxy parameters (host, username, host and password) in .net webbrowser component?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, proxy, browser

i'm trying to set configurations of proxy in navigation with webbrowser, but i don't know how to pass the user and password.
I'm tried to use this way to set proxy configuration :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2011/04/26/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-the-webbrowser-control-in-net.aspx

it's works if i pass only the host and port, but if i pass the user and password it's don't work
(i'm pass using this format : "user:password@host:port")

Somebody can help me?

Thank's

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a proxy for Webbrowser Control without effecting the SYSTEM/IE proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499568/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-webbrowser-control-without-effecting-the-system-ie-proxy)