# how to add proxy to webbrowser1 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, proxy, browser

I have a webbrowser refresher in vb.net but I would like to put a proxy to the webbrowser I don't know how this works.

Here's my code below :

```
Public Class Form1



    Private Property cpn As String

    Private Property video As String

    Private Property video1 As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick



        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")


        lblCount.Text += 1


    End Sub



    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

So for example I want a proxy.text box where I can put in the proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a proxy for Webbrowser Control without effecting the SYSTEM/IE proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499568/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-webbrowser-control-without-effecting-the-system-ie-proxy)

Comment: ok but i dont know how to put that in my code i have now allready?? can you show me that by adding it to my code?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 can you show me how to implement that in my script?