# How do I set each TWebBrowser to use an independent proxy?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I have found all kind of [examples](http://www.entwickler-ecke.de/topic_TwebBrowser+und+ProxyConfig_83943,0.html) about how to make TWebBrowser use a proxy (like 202.8.128.5:8080). 
However all those examples are changing the proxy globally for all running instances of TWebBrowser. I have two instances. How do I set a different proxy for each browser?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328.aspx#INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION

Comment: Those options apply to the WinInet API, which `TWebBrowser` does not use.  It uses the `IWebBrowser2` interface instead.  Although `IWebBrowser2` is a wrapper for Internet Explorer, which itself uses WinInet internally, you cannot apply per-instance WinInet options to `IWebBrowser2`. They can only be used when the WinInet API is being used directly.

Comment: That's too bad. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: @Beno - check out my answer, that should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the following code (public code, not mine):

```
{$DEFINE DELPHI2009_UP}

function SetProxy(Server: String): Boolean;
// Server z.B. '127.0.0.1:8080' oder ''
type
  INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION = record
    dwOption: DWORD;
    Value: record case Integer of 1: (dwValue: DWORD);
    2: (pszValue: {$IFDEF DELPHI2009_UP}PWideChar{$ELSE}PAnsiChar{$ENDIF});
    3: (ftValue: TFileTime);
  end;

end;
LPINTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION = ^INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION;
INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST = record dwSize: DWORD;
pszConnection:
LPTSTR;
dwOptionCount:
DWORD;
dwOptionError:
DWORD;
pOptions:
LPINTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION;
end;
LPINTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST = ^INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST;

const
  INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1;
  INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2;
  INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3;
  INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4;
  INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5;
  PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = $00000001;
  PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = $00000002;
  PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL = $00000004;
  PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT = $00000008;
  INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
  INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75;
  INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;

var
  OptionsList: INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST;
  BufSize: DWORD;
  HInternet: Pointer;
  Agent: String;

begin
  Result := False;
  BufSize := SizeOf(OptionsList);
  OptionsList.dwSize := BufSize;
  OptionsList.pszConnection := nil; // nil -> LAN, sonst Verbindungsname
  OptionsList.dwOptionCount := 3; // 3 Optionen werden gesetzt
  OptionsList.pOptions := AllocMem(3 * SizeOf(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION));
  try
    if not Assigned(OptionsList.pOptions) then
      EXIT;
    OptionsList.pOptions^.dwOption := INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
    OptionsList.pOptions^.Value.dwValue := PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT or
      PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;
    inc(OptionsList.pOptions);
    OptionsList.pOptions^.dwOption := INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
    OptionsList.pOptions^.Value.pszValue := PChar(Server);
    inc(OptionsList.pOptions);
    OptionsList.pOptions^.dwOption := INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
    OptionsList.pOptions^.Value.pszValue := 'local';
    dec(OptionsList.pOptions, 2);
    Agent := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);
    HInternet := InternetOpen
      ({$IFDEF DELPHI2009_UP}PWideChar{$ELSE}PAnsiChar{$ENDIF}
      (Agent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, nil, nil, 0);
    try // Optionen setzen
      Result := InternetSetOption(HInternet,
        INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, @OptionsList, BufSize);
      InternetSetOption(HInternet, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, nil, 0);
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(HInternet);
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(OptionsList.pOptions); // Speicher freigeben
  end;
end;
```

- Drop **two** `TWebBrowser` components on your form and **two** `TButton`
- `TWebBrowser` components will have the default names **WebBrowser1** and **WebBrowser2**
- The two`TButton` will have the default names **Button1** and **Button2**
- Add `WinInet` to your `uses` clause

Call the above function in `Button1`

Code for `Button1` `OnClick` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
SetProxy('ip:port');
WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.whatismyipaddress.com');
end;
```

Code for `Button2` `OnClick` event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
SetProxy('ip:port');
WebBrowser2.Navigate('www.whatismyipaddress.com');
end;
```

And here is how it looks:

[image]

On the left is WebBrowser1 with a proxy and on the right is WebBrowser2 with a different proxy - both browsers are in the same application and apparently they worked. I've also visited the address from my regular browser (Chrome) while the application was running and it indeed showed up as using my original connection.

So, it works. The WebBrowser components are using their assigned proxy's while the browser on my pc remains unaffected (isn't using either of the proxy's)

Tested this using Rad Studio 10.2 Tokyo just now.
Good luck :)

**UPDATE**

As highlighted in the comments, a way to set the proxy that will be used to navigate, without setting it at design time or in the button you use to `Navigate` is by using a `TStringList` and loading it from a file (.txt, for example). This can be used in the `TWebBrowser` `OnBeforeNavigate2` **event**.

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);

var
proxylist: TStringList;

begin
proxylist:= TStringList.Create;
proxylist.LoadFromFile('proxylist.txt');
SetProxy(proxylist.Strings[0]); //adds the proxy from the 1st line in the txt
proxylist.Free;
end;
```

Create a .txt file named proxylist in your application folder and write the proxy there.

Now you'll have a proxy set for your `TWebBrowser` before you begin to navigate. Either way, I'm sure there a lot of ways to expand this so use your imagination.

Comment: What happens if you add a third button which calls `Navigate()` on both browser controls without setting the proxy first? I didn't test but assume that this will prove that the two browser instances do not in fact use independent proxies but just the last one that was set.

Comment: @mghie The question was how do you set a different proxy for each `TWebBrowser` without changing the global setting on the system or each other. You can set the proxy in the `TWebBrowser` `OnBeforeNavigate2` event, either at design time or by using a TStringList and loading a proxy from a .txt/.ini list in the program folder, indicating which line to load, looping them and so forth. I've just tested that and I can confirm this approach also works and saves you the trouble, you can navigate freely once its set using the event.