# Delphi TWebBrowser - override proxy wihout affecting system settings

Tags: delphi, proxy, twebbrowser

All the solutions I have found depends on changing settings in the registry globally for he user.

With WinInet it is possible to override the proxy without affecting system settings.

Can anyone come up wih a way to do similar for the embedded TWebBrowser - so far my search has been futile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499568/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-webbrowser-control-without-effecting-the-system-ie-proxy

Comment: limitless' suggestion appears interesting - will research further - thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set each TWebBrowser to use an independent proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717411/how-do-i-set-each-twebbrowser-to-use-an-independent-proxy)

Comment: @Tom check my answer at the link vaultah indicated.

Comment: @tcsh: FYI I didn't downvote your answer, but link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Besides, if you find yourself linking to your (or somebody else's) answer on SO, it's a sign that the questions may be duplicates and should be closed as such.

Comment: @vaultah hence me deleting the answer and comments here and just flagging, thanks. [wasn't assuming you down voted]